# Android crash related to android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:563)

Tags: android

An app gets quite a few crashes with the following stack trace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:563)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4530)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:735)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:409)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:555)
```

The stack trace does not have any trace of the app's code.  Considering the large user base, it is relatively rare (about 1 per 10K active devices per day).  I cannot figure out any clues from the above information.  Could anyone shed some light on this to help prevent this crash?

Edit (2017-06-14):
The following screenshot of Google Play Console shows that the top 6 crash clusters do not have app code in their stack traces:
[image]

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
in android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
in android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked

in tgkill

in tgkill

java.lang.IllegalStateException
in android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader

Comment: Are you sure it has something to do with your app?

Comment: @Reaper  They are reported under Crashes of Google Play console.  Google Play console changed recently and is reporting much more crashes than before.  Your question is making me think about contacting Google support to ask for some clarification.

Comment: You could search for some testing apps/libs to stress-test your app and see if it crashes.

Comment: @Hong please tell that you've found smth about that `IllegalStateException`... I'm getting `java.lang.RuntimeException: at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication`

Comment: @snachmsm  I still have not found anything in our code related to this.  The crash still happens occasionally.